# SQL query not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get records between to date from mysql database. I wrote this but it does not work :

```
$from_date = "2012-06-19";
$to_date = "2012-06-24";

SELECT * 
  FROM `contracts` 
 WHERE `indate` >= '$from_date' 
   AND `indate` <= '$to_date' 
 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

My dates are : `2012-06-20` , `2012-06-21` , `2012-06-22` , `2012-06-23`

Comment: look at the mysql BETWEEN() function

Comment: When you say *"it doesn't work,"* what does that mean? Are you getting an error? If so, on the PHP side or the MySQL side? Or is it not returning the rows you're expect? Or is it not returning any rows at all? And what is the data type of `indate`? Please be more specific.

Comment: Can you show the actual PHP code?  I don't see anything wrong with your SQL - it should return the dates you specified.  Have you tried running this SQL directly through a MySQL client, instead of PHP?  That's a good way to narrow down if the error is coming from PHP or MySQL.  And as NullUserException said, what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing should work fine.  I select from date fields like this all the time at work.

```
mysql> create table contracts (indate date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into contracts values ('2012-10-06'), ('2012-11-04'), ('2012-09-17');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> set @from_date = '2012-10-01';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @to_date = '2012-10-31';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from contracts where indate >= @from_date and indate <= @to_date;
+------------+
| indate     |
+------------+
| 2012-10-06 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I used mysql variables here of course, but there's nothing to them; they just contain strings.  You could do this instead:

```
mysql> select * from contracts where indate >= '2012-10-01' and indate <= '2012-10-31';
+------------+
| indate     |
+------------+
| 2012-10-06 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The O.P. are right though, BETWEEN is much more succinct:

```
mysql> select * from contracts where indate between '2012-10-01' and  '2012-10-31';
+------------+
| indate     |
+------------+
| 2012-10-06 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The magic of the date comparison is because the field is of date type.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM contracts 
     WHERE indate >= to_date('2012-06-19','yyyy-mm-dd') 
       AND indate <= to_date('2012-06-24','yyyy-mm-dd') 
     ORDER BY id DESC
```